# How to perform outset operation on a polygon in Raphael Javascript?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I could not find any methods in Raphael to perform an "outset" operation on a polygon. The closest I could find was transforming the size, which really is not the same thing.

Given a polygon, how would I outset the path?

Comment: Not possible with the buit-in features, I'm afraid. You could write a function that finds the center and then offsets each node x pixels from the center.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael has not support for this (for now), but with the new Javascript Clipper you can achieve the outset of polygon easily.

This is an example of outset polygon:

[image]

Check the [LIVE DEMO](http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.2/main_demo.html) of Javascript Clipper.

and get the clipper.js file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/ .

There is also [step-by-step instructions](https://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home/#b-offsetting-polygons) how to use the library.

Hope this helps.